# Sharding not enabled on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, sharding

On a Kubernetes Clusters, using a bitnami helm ,On a Database mongo 6.0.1,I have created a database previously and applied a new collection on it and it was working but recently the sh.enableSharding() is working on a database which i have created but by applying sh.ShardCollection it displays "MongoServerError: sharding not enabled for db".

I have created different databases for testing purpose but all of them are facing the same issue.

**Command:**

```
[direct: mongos] my_db> sh.enableSharding("my_db")
```

**Output:**
{
ok: 1,
'$clusterTime':

```
{     clusterTime: Timestamp(\{ t: 1678966557, i: 1 }
),
signature:

{       hash: 
Binary(Buffer.from("b5da1b9a2539ecdaf77096012e36a014b51c492b", 
"hex"), 0),       keyId: Long("7925145979144201565")     }
},
operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1678966557, i: 1 })
}
```

**Command:**

```
[direct: mongos] my_db> sh.shardCollection("my_db.my_collection", {"_id": "hashed"})
```

**Output:**

```
`MongoServerError: sharding not enabled for db my_db`
```

Comment: I think you should create a ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org/. According [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/sh.enableSharding/#mongodb-method-sh.enableSharding) command `sh.enableSharding(database)` is not required anymore, but you faced just the opposite.

Comment: Why wouldn't sh.enablingSharding(database) required anymore?